# Should I use socket or nio for a server with only several clients?

Tags: java, sockets, nio

I have a program, which read real-time socket data from a external source, and broadcast them to several clients as fast as it can. The data bandwidth from source is 200K, and the clients is less than 10.

The server and clients are in an intranet, and gigabit ethernet card.

Currently, I'm using mina 1.x, which is nio framework. But I found the performance is not as good as I expected.

I'm thinking, is it correct to use nio for this application? (I heard nio is good for thousand s of clients)

Does traditional socket have better performance than nio in this case?

Comment: what kind of performance are you seeing?  What do you want it to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience blocking NIO performs best for a small number (around 10) connections.  However, any approach you uses is usually fast enough to saturate a 10 Gig-E network.  (It only matters over loopback, or if you have much more than 10 Gig-E bandwidth)

What network are you using? What numbers are you getting?

Here is an old test I did. http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2010/07/java-nio-is-faster-than-java-io-for.html  Even one client saturates a 1 Gb connection using either approach. This was run on an old PC BTW.

Comment: The server and clients are in an intranet, and gigabit ethernet card.

Comment: @PerterLawrey, from your blog, NIO has always better performance than socket? No matter how many clients there?

Comment: Blocking NIO works very well for small to medium numbers connections.  For large numbers of connections I would use **non-blocking** NIO.  I would use IO if you have libraries which require Input/OutputStreams.

Comment: NIO is blocking by default, just like IO. NIO is often made non-blocking which adds some complexity, but you don't have to use non-blocking NIO.